Bulk Java Project Module Import in Intellij IDEA
I have 71 plain Java projects in a folder. In Eclipse, I can use the 'import existing projects into workspace' feature to load all Java projects into my Eclipse instance at once.
Is there a similar feature in IntelliJ IDEA? I know that IDEA uses modules, and I can add each project individually as a module, but is there a way to import multiple modules at once?
My folder structure is as follows:
/Projects/JavaProject1/src/Main.java
/Projects/JavaProject2/src/Main.java
......

I followed this Stack Overflow thread link and wanted to know if there is any bulk module import option in IntelliJ IDEA.
eclipseImport.png
ideaImport

Does each project consist of just the one .java file, no other source code files?

Are these projects built with Maven or Gradle?

Yes, they have a single or several *.java files under a default package. These aren't maven or gradle projects. I used to create new standalone java projects in Eclipse for each problem on leetcode/gfg or each contests codeforces/codechef), with the project name corresponding to the problem name or contest date. Now that I've switched to IntelliJ Idea, I am looking for a way to mass import these projects as modules.

You can try the new Workspace plugin.
From the blog post on [How to use workspaces]:(https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2024/08/workspaces-in-intellij-idea/#how-to-use-workspaces)

Create a workspace as a new project type.
Give your workspaces folder a name and add all required projects to it.
There are some current limitations described in the blog post.

For more information, see the blogpost or the related livestream

Thanks @Marit, plugin worked like a charm, The workspace plugin experience was similar to that of an eclipse import, although I had to add *.java file folder manually as a source in project settings, it's no big deal. Hopefully the plugins gets support in future to auto detect source folders for standalone java projects like it does for maven/gradle project today. Thanks again, Cheers!

@VashistaBasava - Good to hear! Please let us know if you have any additional feedback. You can find the links in the the blogpost I linked above.

Yes we can bulk load modules in intellij with help of a plugin
Bulk Load Modules Plugin 
File > Settings > Plugins

Hi @Sharad, I have ran into an error saying 'The plugin is incompatible with my current IDE version' - I am on IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3 (Community Edition) - What version of the idea are you on?

“Updated 14 years ago”

Apologies Vashista for the plugin incompatibility issues.
For some reason I am still stuck with ideaCE v 2018.3.6.
Meanwhile in your latest version of idea is there an option to browse and select all the .iml files or directories containing .iml files.

@Sharad, since these projects were created using eclipse earlier there is no .iml file for them. IDEA is generating one when I add them individually as modules for the first time.
